# Sometimes Google Sheet's cell boundaries appear broken/uneven. How can I fix it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried reloading the page but to no avail. The uneven boundary persists. How can I fix the issue?

[image: Uneven cell boundary]

Comment: One of the cells probably has a background color or border. Hint: white background is not the same as no background.

Comment: @Clashsoft , I rechecked. Cells don't have borders. Also, I'm assuming "Fill colour" and "Background colour" mean the same. That way, both cells have different colours. In this case, it's based on custom fill formatting based on a function.

Comment: And the cells to the left? The white 25/03 and 26/03. Do they habe a fill color?

Comment: @Clashsoft Turns out that theme colour was the culprit. 25/03, 26/03 cells had the "white theme" turned on, under the fill settings, unlike other cells in the same column, which had white fill only. I reset the fill settings for these two cells, and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to play with zoom (sometimes it helps) - **<kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + **<kbd>+</kbd>**</kbd>** & **<kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + **<kbd>-</kbd>**</kbd>**

if not then you can reset formatting of all 4 cells with **<kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd></kbd>**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Clashsoft https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwDle.png

Comment: I tried both the suggestions, but nothing's working. It permanently shows uneven boundaries. The issue gets visible, especially when conditional formatting is applied.

Comment: @player0 Here's the link to the copy of that document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J9TsFRw1So0e7CZJBoXX34tOiLFV4banwuXrrGN7Nok/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnuragPradhan https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMdEZA-_H3UYI4ua62o4VfUQrkfv3QDR3xwLhn-CYsk/edit#gid=1263405931

Comment: @player0 It worked! Thanks. However, I'm curious to know what went wrong—the root cause of the problem. I still don't know why it behaved the way it did.

Comment: @AnuragPradhan for me it happens when I copy/paste stuff from somewhere